# Abstract Classes and ReadOnly Properties

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop

Let's have three classes;

```
Line
PoliLine
SuperPoliLine
```

for all that three classes a `Distance` is defined.

But only for the `Line` a `Distance` can be Set.

Is there a possibility to build a common *abstract* (MustInherit) class **`Segment`**, having a **`Distance`** as (abstract +? *ReadOnly*) member?

Question for *VB.NET*, but C# answers welcomed too.

---

**Business Background**

Imagine a Bus. It has a lot of `Station`s, `MainStation`s, and 2 `TerminalStation`s. So *Line* is between 2 Stations, *PoliLine* is between 2 `MainStation`s, and `SuperPoliLine` is between 2 TerminalStations. All "lines" are "Segments", but only the distance A->B between 2 stations - *Line* can be defined.

Comment: You want Segment class be inherited from Line?

Comment: @Andrew Bezzub: Yes. I changed *Line* with *Segment* :) to me more "realistic". So *Line* should inherit from *Segment*.

Comment: For all I know a polyline is not a line. Since a "is a" relationship is not given, polyline should rather be a composition of lines but not be downcastable to line, not even segment. Maybe declaring interfaces would be a better fit here. In that case, superpolyline does not make much sense, as multiple polylines are also a polyline

Comment: Serhio, your design is incoherent.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override and re-declare (to add the set) at the same time - but you can do:

Base class:

```
protected virtual int FooImpl { get; set; } // or abstract
public int Foo { get { return FooImpl; } }
```

Derived class:

```
new public int Foo {
    get { return FooImpl; }
    set { FooImpl = value; }
}

// your implementation here... 
protected override FooImpl { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

Now you can also override FooImpl as needed.

Comment: users should *not* be able to *set* a Distance to PoliLine (derived class), but to *Line*;

Comment: Since `PolyLine` can't be substituted for `Line` it shouldn't be derived from it. Perhaps give them a common baseclass.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It can be. See a Line as a Curve if you want. That is a sample, but in my real project it can be.

Comment: Being able to set a Distance on Line of not it's derived class is a strong sign that your class hierarchy is badly designed. There are exceptions where thus a design is a good idea, but those cases are rare.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want it settable in one class but unsettable in the others, I would customarily not use a property for the one that is “special” (the setter in this case).

```
public class Segment
{
    protected int _distance;
    public int Distance { get { return _distance; } }
}

public class Line : Segment
{
    public int SetDistance(int distance) { _distance = distance; }
}
```

Comment: yeah, public method to add... this is what I did. Remark that Distance should be "abstract" member in Segment. If no other solution, I will remain with this one. However its a little strange to have a property + a Set method :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Segment
{
    private int distance;
    public virtual int Distance
    {
        get { return distance; }
        set { distance = value; }
    }
}

public class Line : Segment
{
    public override int Distance
    {
        get { return base.Distance; }
        set
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

EDITED VERSION:

```
    public abstract class Segment
    {            
        public abstract int Distance { get; set; }
    }

    public class Line : Segment
    {
        private int distance;
        public override int Distance
        {
            get { return distance; }
            set
            {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok, now the Line *should* set `distance = value;` The PoliLine should not. The idea is that user should be compile time stopped to setting the distace to Poliline. If not, he can say that my code does not work, and will have reason. This is not very proper code. A way to bypass that in runtime is to throw in set an exception...

Comment: I appreciate your help, but saying that the design is incoherent without some arguments is like to say "You are stupid".

Comment: No, Serhio, I did not say YOU are stupid. Nor did I imply it. I said your DESIGN was incoherent.

Comment: Upon further review, I've decided that your design is actually a masterpiece of engineering. It will, no doubt, populate textbooks of the future.